# Sending POST data via href

Tags: php, jquery

Is there any way of sending post data via an anchor tag??
for GET data you just have to write it directly in the URL
but can we still do it for POST?
i need the link to be without any parameters and pass name=john via POST. can this be done?

Comment: Is there any way of sending post data via an anchor tag??
for GET data you just have to write it directly in the URL like:

    href="display.php?name=john"

but can we still do it for POST?
i need the link to be

    href="display.php"

and pass name=john via POST

can this be done with jQuery??

Comment: Can you show your code what you have tried? Need little more explanation

Comment: It would be useful (and also interesting) to know why you need this approach.

Comment: You can json_encode the $_POST array and append the resultant string to the url in the link and you can decode the string on the next page to get the original posted data in form of an array.

Comment: i actually need to do something like saving the current url.. for example <a href="/display.php?name=john">John Profile</a> and i want to send the current url as post so when the user has done his job on the href link he is redirected to the POST url

Comment: In general means in good design you should be knowing what URL you have to redirect back to at server side. But still if you want to know what URL made this request, you can do that by checking the value of the http request referer header value. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

Answer (score 6):

Not with plain HTML.

You could use JavaScript to cancel the default behaviour of the link and submit a form (creating the form if needed).

```
jQuery('a').on('click', function (evt) {
    jQuery('form').submit();
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

… but you shouldn't do that because links and submit buttons have different affordances and you'd be sending misleading messages to the user while adding an unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript.

If you want to make a POST request, then do it [for the right reasons](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) and do it with a form and a submit button.

Comment: i actually need to do something like saving the current url..

for example

<a href="/display.php?name=john">John Profile</a>

and i want to send the current url as post so when the user has done his job on the href link he is redirected to the POST url